# How to test multiple Web Services with one script using UFT?

Tags: web-services, testing, automated-tests, hp-uft

I am trying to create a set of Regression Test scripts to test the different Web Services and the corresponding methods related to my Web Application in HP UFT. I am using the API testing feature of UFT. I have the request and response XMLs (obtained manually) of each web service method necessary for the testing. There are more than 50 web service methods to be tested. The test cases for all of them are same. The input data of the request is currently being set by parameterizing the data from an excel spreadsheet.

Since the test cases are exactly same and the input data for all the web service methods have similar fields, such as First Name, Last Name, LoginID etc., I want to know if there is a way to write a single script which dynamically reads the web service method name and the associated data from the spreadsheet and uses it in the request XML file (same name as the web service method) which is also loaded in run time.

In this way, after the script has been developed, all I need to do prepare a list of all the web service methods to be tested and enter them in the Test spreadsheet along with the required request data. The script would loop through all the web service methods and execute the test cases for each web service method one by one.

Answer (score 1):

in your case I think you should use a Soap Request method rather than a Web Service Call. Using soap request, other than the message itself, you can parameterize also the Endpoint Address and the SoapAction
Hope this helps
Yossi

Comment: If the methods schema is the same then you just need to data drive the data. However, if the schema is different then you need to use multiple soap requests. BTW, don't you have a WSDL that you can import and use the web service call method?

Comment: according to your description picking up the required data for the fielads is not enough. If the schema is different then you need to change the structure of the soap dynamically, however this is not possible